# Do the back side of double-faced cards have a color?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, would [Ugin, the Spirit Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUgin%2c%20the%20Spirit%20Dragon%5d)'s minus ability affect [Westvale Abbey](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWestvale%20Abbey%5d) transformed?

> −X: Exile each permanent with converted mana cost X or less that's one or more colors.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can have a color, and Ormendahl would be exiled.

[image: Picture of Ormendahl, Profane Prince]

Do you see the little black dot to the left of "Legendary Creature"?

That dot is called a color indicator, and means that the card is black. The CMC of the back of a double-faced card is the same as the front, which, in this case, is 0.

[image]

Here's another example of a black color indicator.